# How is cross platform mobile development done in practice today (year 2013)?

Tags: android, ios, cross-platform

I am a .NET developer (more than 6 years now) and just starting to learn about mobile/smartphone/tablets development. Logically, I (and probably everybody else out there) would like the application we create to run on all smartphone platforms. It just feels natural from the normal user (layman) perspective that if it's a "mobile app" it should run on mobile device. It shouldn't matter if I own iPhone or Android, mobile app is a mobile app. Note: I am talking about native platform development, not HTML/web apps that can be used from browsers.

So this is just a high-level overview question... what are the current strategies (in year 2013) to deal with this issue? The way I imagine mobile cross platform development works is there's probably  a single common code base that implements app's business logic and then for each targeting platform we need to develop GUI part separately. How far is this from truth in practice?

Take for example the popular game "Angry Birds". I played it on iPhone, Android and even from Chrome browser on Windows Desktop (probably as Flash or HTML5 game) and each version had pretty much identical feeling when played. How did they do that? I imagine they have game engine as common code but in what language could it be written? As far as I know there is no common programming language that given the single source code files it can be compiled into native binaries for ios/android/win8 phone.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no way to develop a cross-platform app which has really native look and feel and shares same code for all platforms.
Its possible to share some code on some platforms though (for example, you can use C/C++ for iOS and Android), but only for the logic part of your app. To get native UI you will be forced to use native APIs. If your app doesn't involve some complicated data processing then this approach may have more downsides than really helping you out.
You can get rather good platform independence with hybrid app platforms such as PhoneGap or Titanium, but that involves HTML/Javascript development which could lead to a lot of time and efforts required to bring user experience to be somewhat similar to that of a native app.

Comment: Agree with the above. I think PhoneGap made more sense in the early days of iOS development, when there were not many people outside of Apple who were well-versed in Objective C, but a lot of people who knew web technologies. Now, Obj-C is one of the top 10 programming languages and there are plenty of talented native developers. I have researched using it in order to expand my capabilities into Android, but concluded that it made more sense to either learn that SDK or subcontract.

Comment: I wouldn't write off PhoneGap due to the reasons listed.  In all reality the majority of your UI changes could be had by simply using a different CSS file for each device or you could always just be less concerned with looking 100% native.  Buttons will look like a default button that appears in a browser...as will the other elements.  Both options listed in my answer can easily be adapted to  any platform that is supported by changing just the UI layers (CSS for phonegap and a UI project for Xamarin). My reason for skipping phonegap would be performance...not appearance.

Comment: I didn't say that they should avoid PhoneGap or the like. Actually, it could be a great solution to roll out an app for all major platforms quickly and then (if needed) migrate to native UI step by step. The point of my answer was that there is no silver bullet. There are some ways to go, but all have their drawbacks.

Comment: Gotcha, also just FYI Xamarin is very close to a Silver bullet (IMO).  It compiles down and the UI is still done via their API.  Not the native.

Comment: Titanium compiles down to native UI nowadays, See [slide 18](http://www.slideshare.net/slideshow/embed_code/22808619). Xamarin however is very straight forward differing from Titanium in that one UI must be made for each platform, whilst Titanium compile down the same UI code to multiple platform representations. Another source stating:"You are using the platform’s backend UI controllers, behaviors, and animations, which offers the native experience that most users expect." is found [here](http://forumone.com/blogs/post/what-titanium-appcelerator-really-and-how-it-works)

Answer (score 3):

Since you are a .NET Dev one logical solution for you would be to use Xamarin's offerings. (http://xamarin.com/) They allow you to develop your back-end logic once and then compile it into all three major mobile platforms (iPhone/Android/WP).  You can then use this back-end logic project to write the UI layer for each specific platform.

Another option that devs have is to use the javascript/html route similar to [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/).  While I haven't looked at this recently there used to be some performance hits and hardware usability gaps when going the JS/HTML route.  This may have been improved now.

EDIT:
Since you specifically mentioned games like Angry Birds.  The [Unity](http://unity3d.com/unity/multiplatform/) platform offers very good support for development that is compatible with most devices if you need 3D.

For Angry Birds specifically...they use [Box2D](http://box2d.org/) for the Physics and I'm not 100%, but it looks like Cocos2d to draw the elements.

If you are looking to build games and like the idea of Xamarin then take a look at [MonoGame](http://monogame.codeplex.com/releases/view/102870) which basically looks like an XNA port to the Mono Framework.

Answer (score 2):

in addition of Jared's answer, this afternoon I tested Xamarin.

You are a .Net Developer and if you are already using Visual Studio, you are so lucky. Because  Xamarin has an `extension for Visual Studio`

I just want to give a bad impression about xamarin, you can test good ones by the time, user interface is created in a xml based file and there is no auto complete, so you have to write whole code or use properties window. But I think it will be better by the time. nice coding

Comment: Actually, all platforms have free visual editors for the UI.  You may need to tweak the XML, but there isn't a single platform (that Xamarin supports) that REQUIRES you to touch the XML. Windows Phone = Expression Blend (Expression is going away at some point though)/Android has a few options, but one is DroidDraw/iPhone this is part of XCode? (don't remember the exact name, but you download it as part of the iOS license/dev kit)

Comment: I think there is a misunderstanding here. I just wanted to say it!s an plus for Xamarin that has Visual Studio. Then If you check the component source page, there is a xml based syntax and i didn't access the auto complete. I'm not talking about seperate xml file.